# Visual Basic Form Application custom close button

Tags: vb.net, exit

I created a new UI style like Visual Studios 2012 (the upper line with close button for example)

Now I try to close the application when I click on it (hovering works fine) but when I click on it the form closes, but the program doesn't stop debugging.

Is there any way I can make the program stop debugging?

Me.Close(), Application.Exit() and Application.ExitThread() does **not** work.

Comment: What happens if you wait some seconds and hit *Break All* in the debugger?

Comment: I don't have a debugger because I use windows form application.

Comment: How does creating a windows form application prevents you from using a debugger? Didn't you ask how to *make the program stop debugging*? Maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: If I use my codes the form closes, but Visual Studio doesn't stop debugging.

Comment: Post a small sample code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Application.Exit()
        Application.ExitThread()
    End Sub`

Now visual studios is still debugging, but the form is closed.

Comment: If you click the Menu Debug, is the submenu 'Terminate Debug' enabled?

Comment: I don't get that submenu, but now I found out it closes in 5/10 seconds, any way I can speed that up?

Comment: Does the statement End do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in your Project Properties Menu. There is the option to choose when the program ends. Options will be like, "First Form Opened Closes", "Last Form Closes" ect.

It may be that you have opened another form and only Hidden it, not closed it. Hence it is still open and the application will not close.

Alternatively, just type the word "End" that will force the program to close

Regards

Joe

Comment: What was the problem? Was it the 'End' or the form closure order from the project properties drop down?

Comment: I tried out End and that worked. However it sometimes take around 5 seconds and while that it's freezed, and after 5 seconds, it closes.